# How to ignore some fields in MapStruct when using the new @SubclassMapping annotation?

Tags: java, mapstruct

## Initial situation

Using current 1.5.0.Beta2 MapStruct release with JDK 13.

### Domain Model

```java
class Wrapper {
    private Fruit fruit;
}
```

```java
abstract class Fruit {
    private int weight;
    /* ... */
}

class Apple extends Fruit {
    /* ... */
}

class Banana extends Fruit {
    /* ... */
}
```

(Corresponding 1:1 DTOs omitted)

### Mappers

#### Mapper for Wrapper class

```java
@Mapper(uses = {FruitMapper.class})
public interface WrapperMapper {
    WrapperDto map(Wrapper wrapper)
}
```

#### Mapper for Fruit class(es)

MapStruct `Mapper` for **abstract** `Fruit` class with method signature and annotations:

```java
@Mapper(subclassExhaustiveStrategy = SubclassExhaustiveStrategy.RUNTIME_EXCEPTION /*...*/)
public interface FruitMapper {
    @SubclassMapping(source = Apple.class, target = AppleDto.class)
    @SubclassMapping(source = Banana.class, target = BananaDto.class)
    FruitDto map(Fruit fruit);
}
```

## Problem

The above works fine until a field needs to be ignored on the referenced abstract class (e.g. the `weight` of a `Fruit`).
Putting this annotation to the `WrapperMapper` `map` method...

```java
@Mapping(target = "fruit.weight", ignore = true)
WrapperDto map(Wrapper wrapper)
```

...leads to `The return type FruitDto is an abstract class or interface. Provide a non abstract / non interface result type or a factory method.` compile error.

## Question

Is there a way to skip fields in MapStruct mapping as outlined without getting this compile error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Cause

What happens is that because you designate it on the WrapperMapper it will not directly use the FruitMapper. Instead the WrapperMapper implementation will get a new mapping method generated to map fruits. MapStruct fails at this attempt and gives you that compile error.

## Solution

If you add that ignore to the FruitMapper it would inherit it to both subclassmappings:

```
        @SubclassMapping( source = Apple.class, target = AppleDto.class )
        @SubclassMapping( source = Banana.class, target = BananaDto.class )
        @Mapping( target = "weight", ignore = true )
        FruitDto map( Fruit fruit );
```

In case you want to have a mapping with weights and one without weights you could add the `@org.mapstruct.Named` annotation to the one without weights and then use this at the WrappedMapper.

like this:

```
    @Mapper(subclassExhaustiveStrategy = SubclassExhaustiveStrategy.RUNTIME_EXCEPTION /*...*/)
    public interface FruitMapper {
        @SubclassMapping( source = Apple.class, target = AppleDto.class )
        @SubclassMapping( source = Banana.class, target = BananaDto.class )
        FruitDto map( Fruit fruit );

        @SubclassMapping( source = Apple.class, target = AppleDto.class )
        @SubclassMapping( source = Banana.class, target = BananaDto.class )
        @Mapping( target = "weight", ignore = true )
        @Named( "NoWeights" )
        FruitDto map( Fruit fruit );
    }

    @Mapper(uses = {FruitMapper.class})
    public interface WrapperMapper {
        @Mapping( target = "fruit", qualifiedByName = "NoWeights" )
        WrapperDto map(Wrapper wrapper)
    }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Many thanks @Ben, the solution with different mapping method with `@org.mapstruct.Named` annotation works like a charm!